# How do i keep a row connected together(moving together) while shifting/adding row above it?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel file containing two sheets:

- `Teams` (which contains details of teams and time schedule of their matches)
- `Results` (contains calculation and number of matches and results, etc).

What`Results`did is that each game that has launched status on `Teams` it gets on `Results` sheet and then`Results`input the number and calculation on that sheet.

My problem is that when there is a game inside two started games, when it starts the new name comes and shifts the name row below it and keeps the details of the row below it for itself, while it should be to next of it, here is my example:

### **`Sheet1` `Teams`**

```
    A                          B
1  **Names**                  **Status**

2 TEAM A                       Launched    

3 TEAM B                        Pending

4 TEAM C                       Pending

5 TEAM D                       Launched
```

### **2 `Results`**

```
    A                        B                    C           D             E
1  **Names**          **1st Half goals**    **2nd half**   **total**  **points**

2 TEAM A                       1                  2              3          13

3 TEAM D                       3                  1              4          10
```

So what happens here is that if change the status of TEAM B on `Sheet1` of `Teams` it will be appear on 2 `Results` and it will take the row input of TEAM D.

It will be like this:

### **2 `Results`**

```
    A                        B                    C           D             E
1  **Names**          **1st Half goals**    **2nd half**   **total**  **points**

2 TEAM A                       1                  2              3          13

3 TEAM B                       3                  1              4          10

4 TEAM D
```

Is there any solution? please let me know.

This is the formula on `Sheet 2 Results` Cell `A2`
`=IFERROR(INDEX(TEAMS!A$2:A$550,SMALL(IF(TEAMS!B$2:B$550="Launched",ROW(TEAMS!B$2:B$550)-ROW(TEAMS!B$1)),ROW(TEAMS!B2))),"")`

and `Cell B & C & E` there is no formula only manual input, and for `Cell D` `=SUM(C2,B2)`

Comment: Are you using something like index match to bring the relevant results? That way as the names change position the results get re- calculated and stay with the correct team. You should show what formulae you use at the moment.

Comment: Yes, am using a complex of (IFERROR+INDEX+SMALL) i found that online , I don't know how I did it actually haha. 
This is the actual Formula :
`=IFERROR(INDEX(Names!B$4:B$550,SMALL(IF(Names!M$4:M$550="Launched",ROW(Names!B$4:B$550)-ROW(Names!B$3)),ROW(Names!B1))),"")`

Comment: [These links](https://www.google.ca/search?num=100&q=tutorial+index+match+advanced+lookup+excel) should help.

Comment: @ExcelNoob  -- place this kind of single quotes `\`` around your formulas/code in comments to make it more legible. (More [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/text-formatting-now-allowed-in-comments-list-of-proven-and-disproven-abilities).)

Comment: @ashleedawg Thanks , i will place these quotes from now on. And for your answer , my problem is not with lookup because it brings the names exactly like they are on `Sheet 1 (TEAMS)` , what i want is that when `TEAM B` comes between `TEAM A` and `TEAM D` , the entire row of `TEAM D` to be shifted down with it because the results are related to it not to `TEAM B` ...

Comment: So, that formula you have in the comment, you need to edit your question and put it in there, and then say which cell it is in and add the formulae for cells C2, D2, and E2

Comment: @SolarMike I did, so could you help me now ?

Comment: Please be informed that i have posted same thread on [link]https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1042998-how-make-entire-row-connected-together.html , [link]https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/how-do-i-keep-a-row-connected-together-moving-together-while-shifting-adding-row-above-it.37354 and [link]https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/1219470-how-do-i-keep-a-row-connected-together-moving-together-while-shifting-adding-row-above-it.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer for my question, thanks to [GraH - Guido](https://chandoo.org/forum/members/grah-guido.36949/) & [Vletm](https://chandoo.org/forum/members/vletm.19418/) users on [Chandoo Forum](https://chandoo.org/forum), who helped me find the answer.

I found 2 answers both helpful and working for my case, you can find them [here](https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/how-do-i-keep-a-row-connected-together-moving-together-while-shifting-adding-row-above-it.37354/#post-224421) and [here](https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/how-do-i-keep-a-row-connected-together-moving-together-while-shifting-adding-row-above-it.37354/#post-224491)

Thanks.